# Help : Realtime graphical interface in wxpython

Tags: user-interface, wxpython, real-time

I am new to this post as well as to python GUI programming.I want to make a realtime graphical GUI in wxpython.My requirement is that i have to catch signals from a device and i have to display the data in graphical as well as in textual form.The system should be accurate and be specific with the time constraints.Please can any one guide me in this,and if this be possible in wxpython and if yes how can i and if no what i can use for this is python.

Hoping someone will help me out soon.Thanks in advance and for your concern.

regards,
Anil ph

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to this mysterious device and receive data from it from Python, then you can display said data with wxPython or any other GUI toolkit. You don't really say what kind of data it is or what you want to display? Lines? Graphs? Or what? If it's just tabular data, use the wx.ListCtrl (or ObjectListView) widget. If you need graphs, see the Plot widget or Matplotlib.